# How do I code into my build file a target that prints a list of sourcefiles in ANT

Tags: java, ant

How do I code  into my build file a target that allows one view the names of my source files.  I am new to ant.

Comment: You mean you just want to print a list of the source files?

Comment: oh, you worded it much simpler than i did, yeah i was to print a list of the source files

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
  <target name="print-src">
    <apply executable="echo">
      <fileset dir="src" includes="**/*.java"/>
    </apply>
  </target>
```