# Display source .java files using less utility and ant

Tags: java, xml, ant

I am learning how to use ant as well as making a .xml file.

I want to create a target, `name="display"` for instance, that implements the 'less' utility to display the source `.java` files in the current folder `srcdir="."`.

The call on the command line is pretty much `ant display`.

Thank you.

Comment: Let me be the first: Why?

Comment: Something wrong with `find . -name "*.java" -exec less {} \;`?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30334813/how-do-i-code-into-my-build-file-a-target-that-prints-a-list-of-sourcefiles-in-a/30343443#30343443

Comment: Apparently Oleg's solution works great.

But is there a way to do it with less?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick solution:

```
<target name="display">
    <concat>
        <fileset dir="${src}" includes="**/*.java"/>
    </concat>
</target>
```

EDIT: if you want to use `less` try the following

```
<target name="display">
    <concat destfile="java.concat">
        <fileset dir="${src}" includes="**/*.java"/>
    </concat>
    <exec executable="less">
        <arg value="java.concat" />
    </exec>
</target>
```